# Odoo xml view ParseError: "Invalid view definition

Tags: xml, odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

Can some one notice what is wrong with this view. i'm getting ParseError: "Invalid view definition

```
<record id="project_part_view_tree_wizz" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Project Part List</field>
            <field name="model">project.part</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Parts" editable="bottom">
                    <group>
                        <field name="project_id"/>
                        <field name="number" />
                        <field name="object"/>
                        <field name="stage_id"/>
                        <field name="part_template_id"/>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="user_id"/>
                    </group>
                    <footer>
                        <button name="generate_project_part" string="Generate"
                                type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                        <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link"
                                special="cancel"/>
                    </footer>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Can a tree view have a footer? I don't think so.

Comment: Remove `<footer></footer>`!!  It's used in form view not tree!!

Comment: groups aren't possible, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a tree you can't use `<group>` and `<footer>` tags, please remove these and and try:

```
<record id="project_part_view_tree_wizz" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Project Part List</field>
    <field name="model">project.part</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="Parts" editable="bottom">
        <field name="project_id"/>
        <field name="number" />
        <field name="object"/>
        <field name="stage_id"/>
        <field name="part_template_id"/>
        <field name="name"/>
        <field name="user_id"/>
        <button name="generate_project_part" string="Generate"
                                type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
        <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link"
                                special="cancel"/>
    </tree>
</field>
</record>
```